# How to make non perpendicular loop cuts

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

Usually a cut loop goes perpendicular from one side to the opposite and all around the adjacent faces of the shape. However I want to cut slices off all corners of my shape, from side to side and all around but with a non-perpendicular cut line (as shown in the picture). Is there a quick way to do this for all four corners?

#[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Create loopcuts (CTRL+R) along the vertical faces.
2. Select all the horizontal edges.
3. Use: Edge>>Subdivide.
   [image]
4. Set the number of the cuts at the bottom-left corner.
   [image]
5. Select the loopcuts, what you made in the 1. step.
6. Use Mesh>>Delete>>Dissolve Edges
   [image]

Comment: very nice, wouldn't have thought of this :)

Comment: And it's pretty easy to turn this into [an all-quads mesh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hn2VL.png) if so desired. Select a set of the outer three edges of varied length, then Shift G to Select Similar > Length. Subdivide. Then use Knife Tool with Cut Through enabled from Top View twice in an X pattern.

Comment: @Mentalist The all-quads mesh is always a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

It is not something that it seems you can do directly. But here is a potential workaround:

1. use the knife tool (K then C) to cut through the whole mesh and create a diamond from the centers of the edges (by pressing SHIFT while cutting) and triangles in the corners:

[image]
[image]

2. now you have the proper geometry to add loops in the corners (CTRL+R):

[image]

After that if needed you can remove the excess geometry by selecting edges and pressing CTRL+X to dissolve.